# how to simplify this regular expression

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

how can I simplify this expression without so many ORs?

a(r|i|ir|ri|irr|rri|rr)(ba|b|ab)

The goal is to catch all of these variations:

ariba, airba, arba, arib, airb, arriba, arrba, airrba, airab, ariab

You can see it here:  https://regex101.com/r/vbQRGF/1

Comment: Would this be good enough? `a(ir?r?|r?ri?)(a?b|ba?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is for it to shorter, then that is possible, but it will match more than what you've specified:

```
a[ri]{1,3}[ab]{1,2}
```

Comment: I can do you a better one then: `.*` :D